# sails update the doc, nothing happen, not err message

Tags: sails.js, waterline

eventController:

```
newHelper: function(req, res) {
        const eventID = req.body.eventID;
        let newHelper = req.body.newHelper;

        newHelper.eventAssoc = eventID;
        Wapphelprecords.create(newHelper).exec(function(err, newhelper) {
            if (err) {
                return res.serverError(err); }

            sails.log('add new helper:', newhelper);
            return res.json(newhelper);
        });
    }
```

when I do this action, the database nothing happen, and no err message, this is model under blow:

WappeventController model:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        eventID: {
            type: 'integer',
            // autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true,
                // defaultsTo: 0
        },

        openid: {
            type: 'string',
        },

        author: {
            model: 'wappuserinfo'
        },

        content: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        allowShare: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        imageList: {
            type: 'array'
        },
        money: {
            type: 'float',
        },
        helpers: {
            collection: 'wapphelprecords',
            via: 'eventAssoc',
        },
        bestHelper: {
            collection: 'wapphelprecords',
            via: 'eventAssoc',
        }
    },
```

Wapphelprecords Model:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        eventAssoc: {
            model: 'wappevents',
        },
        content: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        contact: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        userInfo: {
            model: 'wappuserinfo'
        },
        bestHelper: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        moneyEarn: {
            type: 'float'
        }
    }
};
```

when I do `newHelper` action, the database nothing happened, and nothing error notice, I just do not understand. need help, thx.

Answer (score 0):

spend whole day to fix it, and finally:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        eventID: {
            type: 'integer',
            // autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,   //<---- set this primarkey to true

            unique: true,
                // defaultsTo: 0
        },

        openid: {
            type: 'string',
        },

        author: {
            model: 'wappuserinfo'
        },

        content: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        allowShare: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        imageList: {
            type: 'array'
        },
        money: {
            type: 'float',
        },
        helpers: {
            collection: 'wapphelprecords',
            via: 'eventAssoc',
        },
        bestHelper: {
            collection: 'wapphelprecords',
            via: 'eventAssoc',
        }
    },
```